# <Flutter> I accidentally deleted the wrap with ××× options in the light bulb in IDE. Where can I re-enable the options?

Tags: flutter, ide

I accidentally deleted the Wrap with ××× options in the light bulb in IDE. Where can I re-enable the options?

[wrap with Column/ Wrap with Container...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dGwh7.png)

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this problem
through this instruction (source: https://github.com/flutter/flutter-intellij/issues/2448)